# Excel: write column and row name connected with specific value?

Tags: excel

I've been trying to write a formula for the next problem but I never get it correct. So:

I have to find Top n values in 2D array and write down row and column names which are connected to that value (without the duplicates!). As an example, here's an array:

```
           A        B       C       D        E        F
    1             Aron    Jamie    Matt   Taylor    Zedd
    2    Aron      -        5       7       6         8
    3    Jamie     5        -       2       4         3
    4    Matt      7        2       -       15        12
    5    Taylor    6        4       15      -         26
    6    Zedd      8        3       12      26        -
```

What should be written down by formula(s), in this example Top 3 values and the names connected with those values:

```
A        B     C
Taylor  Zedd  26
Taylor  Matt  15
Matt    Zedd  12
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data, running this macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, K As Long
    i = 3: j = 2: K = 1

    Do
        Cells(K, "G") = Cells(i, 1)
        Cells(K, "H") = Cells(1, j)
        Cells(K, "I") = Cells(i, j)
        K = K + 1
        j = j + 1
        If Cells(i, j).Value = "-" Then
            j = 2
            i = i + 1
            If i = 7 Then Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Range("G1:I10").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("I1:I10") _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
            .SetRange Range("G1:I10")
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
End Sub
```

will get you complete results in columns **G**, **H**, and **I**.

Pick the top three rows to get the top three results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the duplicates, then you can use Large() to work out the three largest numbers like this:

```
=LARGE($B$2:$F$6,ROW(A1))
```

copied down. With these top 3 in column C you can use these two array formulas for the names:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$6,MIN(IF($B$2:$F$6=C10,ROW($B$2:$F$6))))

=INDEX($A$1:$F$1,MIN(IF($B$2:$F$6=C10,COLUMN($B$2:$F$6))))
```

Confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you change the `ROW(A1)` to `ROW(A1) * 2` and the OP would be able to leave the values as is with the duplicates?  But I like the approach.